# Nested class as a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, stl, containers

I try to write a custom STL-style container. For the sake of simplicity, let's say it's a list. I looked up the standard way to define such a container:

```
template <typename T, typename A = std::allocator<T> > class mylist;
```

Now, I want to manage the nodes of the list using a nested class:

```
(inside mylist)
class node {
    T data;
    node *next;
}
```

It is my understanding that I need not put a `template` specifier in front of the definition of `node` as the compiler will instantiate separate classes `mylist<T,A>::node` for each combination of `mylist`'s template parameters.

However, now I need to allocate memory not only for the data of type `T` itself, but also for their wrapper `node`. Thus, I would like the default template parameter to be of type `std::allocator<mylist<T>::node>`. At that point, though, `mylist` has not yet been declared and the compiler is understandably upset:

```
error: `mylist' was not declared in this scope
```

How would one resolve this conundrum? There are two constraints:

- Normally, I would declare the missing class without fully declaring its contents. However, since it is nested inside the very thing I want to declare, this is not an option.
- I need `node` to be nested as it needs to access the allocator instance of `mylist`. E.g., I have `operator=` declared on `node` where a lot of memory management happens recursively. This might be overkill for a list and you could do that from within `mylist`, thereby dropping the parametric dependence of `node` on `A`, but it is crucial for the data structure I'm implementing.

Comment: It might be worth looking at how g++ implements `std::list`.

Comment: Look at allocator `rebind`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter what the default allocator's type argument is, just the actual type. You can use [`rebind_alloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits) from `std::allocator_traits`:

> `Alloc::rebind<T>::other` if present, otherwise `Alloc<T, Args>` if this `Alloc` is `Alloc<U, Args>`

to get what you need:

```
template <typename T, typename A = std::allocator<T> >
class mylist {
    class node { ... };

    using NodeAlloc = typename std::allocator_traits<A>::template rebind_alloc<node>;
};
```

And then use `NodeAlloc` to get your `node`s. In this way, if the user doesn't specify an allocator, you would get the default `std::allocator<T>` and then use `std::allocator<node>`. This is precisely what you want, without having to expose `node`.

Comment: And isn't this also precisely how the standard library works?

Answer (score 1):

> I need node to be nested as it needs to access the allocator instance of `mylist`

Don't be so sure. They can be friends:

```
template <typename, class> class list;

template <typename T>
struct node {
    // ...
};

template <typename T, class Alloc=std::allocator<T> >
class list {
    friend node<T>;
    // ...
};
```

If you don't want `node` to be accessible outside of your file, just omit it in your header file (`.h` / `.hpp`).

Comment: I always forget about friends... I decided to go with the `rebind_alloc` solution though as it seems tailored to my specific problem.